# Showing "Right hand continuity" , critique and help on solution.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Suppose that $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x) = f(a)$ and $f(a) > 0$. Prove there is a number $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) >0$ for all $x$ satisfying $0 \leq x - a < \delta$

The issue I'm having is linking the ideas properly to make the solution sound.

So the rough work I have to this point is:

$$|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon \\ f(a) - \epsilon < f(x) < \epsilon + f(a)$$

So my thinking leads along the lines of "if I can somehow make $(f(a) - \epsilon) = 0$ from my initial conditions then I would be done"

This revolves around me finding "a good $\epsilon > 0$". From the definition of the limit given I have

$$\forall \ \epsilon > 0 \, \exists \ \delta > 0 \ \text{such that,} \text{for all } x\ \text{if} \ 0 < x-a < \delta \ \Rightarrow \ |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$$

Using $$0 < x-a < \delta \\ a< x < \delta + a < \delta + x$$

Here is where I'm stuck....I know from seeing a solution that I'm supposed to eventually draw a conclusion that $|f(x) - f(a)| < f(a)$ and this would lead to $f(x) > 0$. What I'm stuck with is how to "choose the $\delta$" based on the information I have....I also think I'm missing a line of reasoning for myself internally on how to manipulate the expressions.

Comment: You are focusing too much on the $\delta$.  Go back to "if I can somehow make $(f(a)−\epsilon)=0$ from my initial conditions then I would be done" and solve for $\epsilon$ here.  As long as $\epsilon >0$ you can choose any value you want.  The $\delta$ is guaranteed to exist by the assumed limit, so there's nothing to solve for the $\delta$ (best i can tell, you are mixing up the process of proving a limit with using an assumed limit in a proof)

Comment: So when you say "solve for $\epsilon$", this is where my thinking goes: "$\epsilon$ is arbitrary and can be chosen however any person wants to, so me choosing a specific $\epsilon$ doesn't necessarily mean it will be chosen by others"...I'm not saying you are wrong at all I'm just showing you where I "freeze up" when approaching these type of questions. Now with that being said, why would this allow me to choose any $\delta$ I want?

Comment: It doesn't matter what $\epsilon$ other people choose.  How does that matter for _your_ proof?  And again, you cannot choose any $\delta$ you want, but rather using the assumption that the limit exists guarantees _some_ $\delta > 0$ exists.

Comment: To summarize what I see as the confusion: **If you must prove a limit exists**, you must let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary and solve for $\delta >0$, often in terms of $\epsilon$.  **If you use a limit in a proof**, you can choose any fixed $\epsilon>0$ you want, and the existence of the limit implies the existence of some $\delta>0$, but usually we cannot infer anything about $\delta>0$ other than it makes the definition of the limit true for that particular $\epsilon$ you chose.  **For this proof, we are in the second scenario.**

Comment: This is so subtle, but it is EXTREMELY revealing....to me at least. Thank you for this explanation @BrianMoehring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider $\epsilon = \frac{f(a)}{2}$. Outgoing from limit definition for this $\epsilon$ we have $\exists \delta >0$ such that for all x satisfying $0 \leqslant x−a < \delta$  w'll have $$0<f(a) - \epsilon = \frac{f(a)}{2}< f(x)$$ .

Comment: THat makes sense, but how do I define the $\delta$ interval?

Comment: @dc3rd. Added to answer.